# How do I do inline indentation from another book with open office?

Tags: formatting

I'm wanting to do something like the following, but am unsure how to do it:

> As we become attached in the spirit two people developing a shared conscience (Deuteronomy 31:6) of what they may or may not do together because they’re ready, or not ready to do romantic gestures together. When the law of god is inscribed on two hearts (Romans 2:15) becomes natural that they may want to do things that are inappropriate at the phase they were able to prove they can control things at in order to prove they’re ready for the next tasks (Genesis 2:19-25) towards their potential marriage as husband, and wife. Without slowly turning on the fire hose of passion it can easily can lose control (1 Corinthians 9:25), and spray all over creating a lot of harm to both of them (1 Corinthians 9:26) that may last longer than the non-existent commitment they have to each other (1 Corinthians 9:27).
>
> > 25 Everyone who competes in the games goes into strict training. They do it to get a crown that will not last, but we do it to get a crown that will last forever. 26 Therefore I do not run like someone running aimlessly; I do not fight like a boxer beating the air. 27 No, I strike a blow to my body and make it my slave so that after I have preached to others, I myself will not be disqualified for the prize.
>
> Only until they’re ready to give that much more to the other person are they ready to prove they’re ready for the next step so that on the potential wedding night (Revelation 19:6-10) they’re prepared to not degrade each other to only being the tool that makes the other happy (Psalm 37:4). Everyone around you may not know the things going on between the two of you, but you two will, and forget that there’s more than just those addicting activities together that aid in the production of dopamine.

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you're trying to achieve? I'm unsure what you mean by "inline indentation", and it's not clear at all from the text you provided. (In fact, now that I think about it, my edit may well have accidentally removed whatever effect it is you're trying to achieve; if that's the case, feel free to roll it back.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're after is called a "hanging indent" -- commonly used to set off a bock quote.  I've done this in Open Office by changing the left margin (and left indent, if using one) by the necessary amount, pasting or typing the quote, then setting the margin back to default value.  If you need to do it a lot, you may prefer to set up a style so you can do it precisely the same each time, with just a couple clicks.